# discord.py testing for roles not working. always returns false

Tags: python, bots, discord, roles, discord.py

I want a to test if a user has one of two specific roles but for some reason the code i wrote always returns false.

I also tried a different approach, that always returned true. also havent gotten an answer on the discord.py discord server

```
#first approach. always returns false
def isMod(user):
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.id==587614886771687445:
            return True
        elif role.id==587615608279924756:
            return True
    return False



#second approach. always returns true
def isMod(user):
    if discord.utils.get(user.roles, id=587614886771687445) is None and discord.utils.get(user.roles, id=587615608279924756):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

It should return true, if the user has one or both of the roles with the given id and false, if they dont.

Comment: Is `user` the user you're expecting it to be?

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?  You can `print(discord.__version__)` to check.

Comment: im using 0.16.12

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work on my system. You can try a few things here to get this fixed.

1. How are you getting the user name? Try to print out the user name with something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.content.startswith('$'):
            user = message.author
            print(user)
```

Type anything with a $, to invoke this message. If user is properly being printed, next step try to print the role,

```
print(user.roles)
```

This should return an iterable with 'Role id' and 'Name'. Verify if the Role id's are being passed properly.

If you still have problem, share your code on hastebin or something.